# Prove $P \implies Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are statements about rational numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

My goal is to prove the following statement $\left(P\implies Q\right)$ in order to use it as a lemma in another proof.

Given, 
$$P = \left(z\in\Bbb Q \implies \exists \,p,q\in\Bbb Z:z\,=\,\frac pq\wedge q \ne 0 \right)$$
consider the following
$$1+2z=x^2+y^2$$
$$y\;=\;\sqrt {\frac {q+2p}{q}-x^2}$$
on which we impose 
$$x\in(0,1)$$ $$ y\in\Bbb [-1,1]$$
as the domain and range.

We claim
$$Q\;=\;\left(x^2+y^2=\frac {q+2p}{q}\in\Bbb Q\implies x,y\in\Bbb Q:x\in(0,1)\wedge y\in\Bbb [-1,1]\right)$$
so we need to show that 
$$P\implies Q$$
is true.

---

So, since $P$ is true it is left to be shown that $Q$ is also true.

The converse of $Q$ is 
$$\left(Q \; converse \right)\,=\, \left(x,y\in\Bbb Q:x\in(0,1)\wedge y\in\Bbb [-1,1] \implies x^2+y^2=\frac {q+2p}{q}\in\Bbb Q\right)$$
thus, using a result from a previous question ([proof about rational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115723/proof-about-rational-numbers)),

$$\left(x,y\in\Bbb Q:x\in(0,1)\wedge y\in\Bbb [-1,1]\right) \implies \left(\exists\,p,q,r,s\in\Bbb Z: x=\frac pq \wedge y= \frac rs \wedge q,s \ne 0 \right)$$
$$\left(\exists p,q,r,s\in\Bbb Z: x=\frac pq \wedge y= \frac rs \wedge q,s \ne 0 \right)\implies\left( x^2+y^2=\frac {q+2p}{q}\in\Bbb Q\right)$$
$$\therefore \;\left(x,y\in\Bbb Q:x\in(0,1)\wedge y\in\Bbb [-1,1] \implies x^2+y^2=\frac {q+2p}{q}\in\Bbb Q\right)$$
Hence, $\left(Q \;converse\right)$
is true, by contrapositive and so, $Q$ is also true.
$$\therefore\; P\implies Q $$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see how you can deduce that $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ from Q's assumptions.

Comment: Consider $x=\sqrt{3}, y=0, p=q=1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Is this all junk or is there something there that I can use in order to show that $z\in \Bbb Q : 1+2z=x^2+y^2\implies x,y\in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: @TheStrikeofRunningWater Hard to guess what you are after, but in general knowing $x^2+y^2$ tells you nothing about the individual $x,y$. Maybe helps to think of it this way: there are uncountably many points on the unit circle such that $x^2+y^2=1$. But, out of them, only countably many have rational coordinates.

Comment: @dxiv  I was thinking that since I restricted the variables $x \in \left(0,1)\right)$ and $y\in \left[-1,1\right]$ I was avoiding the irrational cases. I am after these "countably many" points $(x,y)$ on the unit circle that intersect a specific line such that $x,y \in\Bbb Q$ but I really want to figure it out on my own. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @TheStrikeofRunningWater Restricting the ranges won't help, since you can always scale $x,y \mapsto \lambda x, \lambda y$ with some rational factor. As for the rest, sorry, but I can't guess what you really have in mind, so I don't know whether the track is right or not (though, honestly, I don't see this one going anywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by dxiv gives a counterexample to the statement in your question. In a comment, you mention that your main goal is to prove that if $z$ is rational and $1+2z=x^2+y^2$, then $x$ and $y$ are rational. **This is also false**: for instance, consider $z=1, x={\sqrt{3}\over 2}, y={\sqrt{3}\over 2}$. And there are many other examples.

The mistake in your proof is when you write

> Hence, [Qconverse] is true, by contrapositive and so, Q is also true.

You are conflating the *converse* and the *contrapositive* here. The *converse* of a statement $\alpha\implies\beta$ is the statement $\beta\implies \alpha$; the contrapositive, meanwhile, is the statement $\neg\beta\implies\neg\alpha$ (where "$\neg$" means "not").

The contrapositive is equivalent to the original statement; if you show that the contrapositive is true, you've shown that the original statement was true. However, *the converse is not*! For example, "If $c=3$ then $c$ is prime" is clearly true, but its converse - "If $c$ is prime then $c=3$" - is equally clearly false.

Comment: I see what you mean about my confusion between converse and contrapositive. Also, doesn't the fact that I restricted the variables $x \in \left(0,1)\right)$ and $y\in \left[-1,1\right]$ mean I am avoiding the irrational cases?

Comment: @TheStrikeofRunningWater No, how would it? E.g. $\pi\over 4$ is irrational but in $(0, 1)$.